# Django modal not load js

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to execute a js function within a Bootstrap modal with a Django filter form.
The modal works fine and i can see the form but some js functionality not works, only if i add again the js inside the filter.html.

base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <body>
    <div class="modal fade" id="custom-modal" role="dialog"></div>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/functions.js' %}"></script>
  <body>
</html>
```

list.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load app_tags %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}
  ...
  <button type="button" class="btn card_header_button" onclick="return openCustomModal('{% url element_filter %}')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Filtrar">
    <span class="fas fa-filter custom_icon"></span>
  </button>
  ...
{% endblock content %}
```

filter.html:

```
{% load static %}
{% load app_tags %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <!-- Here show the form -->
</div>
```

Any idea how to solve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: After page is loaded, does model window open if you paste code like: `openCustomModal('<url_for_element_filter>')` in Inspector console?

Comment: Yes, i can see the opened modal and django filter form

Answer (score -1):

In the file `list.html` try to render button with onclick action without the `return` statement:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load app_tags %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}
  ...
  <button type="button" class="btn card_header_button" onclick="openCustomModal('{% url element_filter %}')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Filtrar">
    <span class="fas fa-filter custom_icon"></span>
  </button>
  ...
{% endblock content %}
```

And also inspect what is the value of onclick listener. It should be something like `"openCustomModal('some-url')"`.

Comment: You're correct the click event show `openCustomModal('/app/presupuestos/filtrar/')`but not solve the js load error on modal.

Comment: What kind of JS load error do you receive?

Comment: No js mistake or error but the range transformation from text input not works

Comment: Please update you question. Now you are talking about, as it seems, completely new problem. What transformation of text input?

Comment: Don't get lost in what my js does, just the js doesn't run